# Get more information from User - Spring Security

Tags: java, security, spring, authentication

I have implemented Spring Security in my application. I have used default implementation, i.e., I have configured it with my own parameters (DataSource, Secured Areas, etc), but I haven't write any Custom implementation.

Now I want to capture more data from the user, that is on the same table as username and password, like company name, id, etc. However, I don't want do use this information in order to login.

I'm not sure how to do it. From what I've read, it's related to UserDetailsService. However, it seems that writing a Custom UserDetailsService would be necessary if I wanted to use this information during the login, and that's not what I want. I just want to use this information inside the application, after the user have logged in.

Is it really related to UserDetailsServer? Is this the only file I have to modificate?

All the examples I found of custom UserDetailsService just used username and password, so I can't understand where new data would come in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overriding the UserDetailsService is what we did.. You'll need to implement your own UserDetailsService and your own UserDetails object:

```
public class CustomService implements UserDetailsService {
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {

        Account account = accountDAO.findAccountByName(username);

        if (account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("account name not found");
        }
        return buildUserFromAccount(account);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    private User buildUserFromAccount(Account account) {

        String username = account.getUsername();
        String password = account.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = account.getEnabled();
        boolean accountNonExpired = account.getAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = account.getCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = account.getAccountNonLocked();

        // additional information goes here
        String companyName = companyDAO.getCompanyName(account);


        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : account.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        CustomUserDetails user = new CustomUserDetails (username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                authorities, company);

        return user;
    }


public class CustomUserDetails extends User{

    // ...
    public CustomUserDetails(..., String company){
         super(...);
         this.company = company;
    }

    private String company;

    public String getCompany() { return company;}

    public void setCompany(String company) { this.company = company;}
}
```

Comment: `loadUserByUsername` returns UserDetails, but in the code, it returns `buildUserFromAccount` that returns a User. So, how the CustomUserDetails is involved in the code? The Account DAO class and all it's methods should be implemented by me, correct?

Comment: Had a little typo in it and fixed it. To explain further: `UserDetails` is the interface, `User` is spring-securities implementation including all basic fields. If you want to add your own fields, the easiest thing to do is to extend `User`. You can still return a `User` object in that method or a `UserDetails` object or a `CustomUserDetails` object as spring security just expects an object that implements `UserDetails`.

Comment: Ah, Ok! So using this, I'm providing everyting Spring Security needs to authenticate. However, the User object it holds has all my custom fields. So, how do I get this object, so I can `getCompany` for example?

Comment: `((CustomUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).getCompany()` should work.

Comment: ((CustomUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getCompany() worked for me